# Finding energy stored in a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electrostatics, capacitance

i am given a voltage time graph for a capacitor circuit. How to find energy stored in that capacitor at various time instants?
Can we just calculate by using $\frac{1}{2}CV^2$
We are given capacitance of that capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we just calculate by using 1/2 CV^2?

Yes.  If $v_C(t)$ is the instantaneous voltage across the capacitor, the instantaneous stored energy is just

$$U_C(t) = \frac{C}{2}v^2_C(t)$$